# Read https url from Python with basic access authentication

Tags: python, authentication, https, passwords

How do you open https url in Python?

```
import urllib2

url = "https://user:password@domain.com/path/
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

gives:

```
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'password@domain.com'
```

Comment: THe way to read https URL's in Python is to actually *search* stackoverflow before posting the same question that's already been asked.  Here's the search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read about the urllib2 password manager and the basic authentication handler as well as the digest authentication handler.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#abstractbasicauthhandler-objects

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#httpdigestauthhandler-objects

Your urllib2 script must actually provide enough information to do HTTP authentication.  Usernames, Passwords, Domains, etc.

Answer (score 11):

This has never failed me

```
import urllib2, base64
username = 'foo'
password = 'bar'
auth_encoded = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]

req = urllib2.Request('https://somewebsite.com')
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % auth_encoded)
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except urllib2.HTTPError, http_e:
    # etc...
    pass
```

Comment: `request.add_header('Authorization', b'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(username + b':' + password))`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass username and password information to `urllib2` you'll need to use an `HTTPBasicAuthHandler`.

[Here's a tutorial showing you how to do it.](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml#doing-it-properly)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass credentials to `urllib2.open` like that. In your case, `user` is interpreted as the domain name, while `password@domain.com` is interpreted as the port number.